# Facebook Pixel: track custom URL

Tags: javascript, facebook-pixel

I want to fire a

```js
fbq('track', 'PageView');
```

event (and its noscript counter part). However, I want to specify the URL that is viewed myself, since the "PageView" in question is actually an overlay and its content is loaded via an XHR request (and the URL stays the same).

However, I am wondering if this is possible at all. The [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-pixel/api-reference#parameters) for the custom parameters don't mention anything about a custom URL for the `PageView` event for example.

Would this work, if I added

```js
window.history.pushState({"html":…},"", this.url);
```

for example, so the URL of the (AJAX loaded) overlay is also in the browser's history and thus the tracking ov `PageView` uses this URL as well?

Comment: Read "custom parameters" as "whatever the hell you like". `fbq('track', 'eventName', {myCustomURL: 'http://stackoverflow.com'});`

Comment: But that would be a custom event - not the `PageView` event.

Comment: According to the docs, a custom event has a custom name, and "track" is a standard event name, which makes it a standard event.

Comment: Yes, but that is not what I mean. _I do not want to track a custom event_. I want to track the `PageView` event, with a _custom URL_.